# Android java code to change displayed spinner

Tags: java, android

Is there a way in android java to change the displayed spinner item to another item in the spinner list?

If I have a spinner that has three items in its arrary can I change the value displayed to the second or third item in the arrary?  I want to create a button that will change all my spinner displayed values to another selection in each of their arrarys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spinner.setSelection(int position) to do this

Comment: You can use spinner.setSelection(int, position)

Answer (score 0):

I have to just tell one thing that this is possible to display dialog with listview also..
Every time you have to pass values to dialog like spinner.

```
public void createSpinner(CharSequence str)
{
    Dialog dialog;

   // final CharSequence str[]={"Android","Black Berry"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Spinner Title");

    builder.setItems(str, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int postion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    dialog=builder.create();

    dialog.show();
}
```